# "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>' with an index of type 'String" error

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I been working on a project that needs to restore the saved data from `.plist`, but I am encountering an error **Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary' with an index of type 'String'** in my code. I am trying to solve it but unfortunately I don't know how. I tried some solution I got here in *stackoverflow* but It didn't worked out. Please help me with this because It is my first time to create a function to restore data. Thank you

[image: error here]

```
 @objc func restoreSucceed() {
    performSelector(inBackground: #selector(stopIndicator), with: nil)
    //エラーアラートビューの表示
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "リストアが完了しました \n (Restore completed)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 {
        var pref = UserDefaults.standard
        //ローカルplist格納先を取得
        let strWorkPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let strPlistPath = "\(strWorkPath)/\(S_DIRECTORY_NAME)/\(S_PLIST_NAME)"
        let dicPref = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: strPlistPath) as Dictionary?
        if let key1 = (dicPref as NSDictionary?)?.keyEnumerator() {
            for key in key1 {
                let strKey = key as? String
                pref.set(dicPref?[strKey ?? ""], forKey: strKey ?? "")
            }
        }
        pref.synchronize()
    }

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Do not use NSDictionary.

Comment: @matt what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses a lot of inappropriate *objective-c-ish* API.

This is the recommended Swift way to read and parse a property list file

```
if #available(iOS 7.1, *) {   
    //ローカルplist格納先を取得
    do {
        let strWorkURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let strPlistURL = strWorkURL.appendingPathComponent("\(S_DIRECTORY_NAME)/\(S_PLIST_NAME)")
        let strPlistData = try Data(contentsOf: strPlistURL)
        guard let dicPref = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: strPlistData, format: nil) as? [String:Any] else { return }
        for (key, value) in dicPref {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

And don't use `performSelector(inBackground:)` either. Use GCD

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    stopIndicator()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following

```
pref.set(dicPref?[strKey! as NSString], forKey: strKey ?? "")
```

@Roy's answer is correct but it will give you warning of unwraps

Answer (score 1):

Replace `dicPref?[strKey ?? ""]` with `dicPref?[strKey as! NSString]`

NB: Avoid force unwrapping if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var pref = UserDefaults.standard
let strWorkPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let strPlistPath = "\(strWorkPath)/\(S_DIRECTORY_NAME)/\(S_PLIST_NAME)"

if let dicPref = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: strPlistPath) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
     // use swift dictionary as normal
     if let key1 = (dicPref as NSDictionary?)?.keyEnumerator() {
         for key in key1 {
             if let strKey = key as? String {
                 pref.set(dicPref[strKey], forKey: strKey)
             }
          }
      }
}

pref.synchronize()
```

Answer (score -1):

replace :

```
let dicPref = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: strPlistPath) as Dictionary?
```

with :

```
 let dicPref = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: strPlistPath)
```

.

```
 let pref = UserDefaults.standard

    let dicPref = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "")
    if let key1 = dicPref?.keyEnumerator() {
        for key in key1 {
            let strKey = key as? String
            pref.set(dicPref?[strKey ?? ""], forKey: strKey ?? "")
        }
    }
```